# Read.table некоректно читает данные

Tags: r

Есть набор данных в тхт формате

```
<TICKER>,<PER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<HIGH>,<LOW>,<CLOSE>,<VOL>,<OI>
EURUSD,5,20180307,080500,1.24210,1.24219,1.24201,1.24214,117,0
EURUSD,5,20180307,081000,1.24217,1.24249,1.24212,1.24236,165,0
EURUSD,5,20180307,081500,1.24235,1.24279,1.24232,1.24259,251,0
EURUSD,5,20180307,082000,1.24260,1.24273,1.24238,1.24248,196,0
EURUSD,5,20180307,082500,1.24247,1.24262,1.24241,1.24259,173,0
EURUSD,5,20180307,083000,1.24257,1.24310,1.24242,1.24302,281,0
EURUSD,5,20180307,083500,1.24298,1.24327,1.24291,1.24310,204,0
итд
```

в строке с "тіме" должно быть **и есть** 6 цифр в формате HHMMSS
но когда я пытаюсь прочесть файл в "R" время читается некорректно, и "шапка" файла тоже

```
d <- read.table(file = "C:/Users/TARAS/Desktop/OHLC.txt",header = T,sep = ",")
head(d)

 X.TICKER. X.PER.  X.DATE. X.TIME. X.OPEN. X.HIGH.  X.LOW. X.CLOSE. X.VOL. X.OI.
1    EURUSD      5 20180307   80500 1.24210 1.24219 1.24201  1.24214    117     0
2    EURUSD      5 20180307   81000 1.24217 1.24249 1.24212  1.24236    165     0
3    EURUSD      5 20180307   81500 1.24235 1.24279 1.24232  1.24259    251     0
4    EURUSD      5 20180307   82000 1.24260 1.24273 1.24238  1.24248    196     0
5    EURUSD      5 20180307   82500 1.24247 1.24262 1.24241  1.24259    173     0
6    EURUSD      5 20180307   83000 1.24257 1.24310 1.24242  1.24302    281
```

Как видно, формат изменился на "HMMSS"

Бывает иногда и такое

```
188    EURUSD      5 20180307  234000 1.24125 1.24137 1.24125  1.24134     45     0
189    EURUSD      5 20180307  234500 1.24130 1.24130 1.24111  1.24116     81     0
190    EURUSD      5 20180307  235000 1.24102 1.24115 1.24095  1.24096     89     0
191    EURUSD      5 20180307  235500 1.24097 1.24105 1.24092  1.24092     42     0
192    EURUSD      5 20180308       0 1.24091 1.24115 1.24091  1.24104     55     0
193    EURUSD      5 20180308     500 1.24103 1.24109 1.24102  1.24107     45     0
194    EURUSD      5 20180308    1000 1.24106 1.24107 1.24103  1.24105     37     0
195    EURUSD      5 20180308    1500 1.24106 1.24109 1.24100  1.24100     20     0
196    EURUSD      5 20180308    2000 1.24099 1.24102 1.24097  1.24098     21     0
197    EURUSD      5 20180308    2500 1.24099 1.24101 1.24096  1.24097     36     0
198    EURUSD      5 20180308    3000 1.24096 1.24110 1.24087  1.24109     81     0
199    EURUSD      5 20180308    3500 1.24108 1.24110 1.24106  1.24107     31
```

Как это исправить?
Напомню что в .txt файле все верно

Comment: Судя по всему, отбрасываются нули в начале чисел, т.к. числа не могут начинаться с 0.. Либо написать функцию, которая будет это значение приводить к 6значному формату(дописать в начале столько нулей сколько не хватает), либо попробовать в тхт хранить это как строку в кавычках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно для функции `read.table` указать аргумент `colClasses`, т.е. типы данных, представленный в каждой колонке:

```
d <- read.table(file = "C:/Users/TARAS/Desktop/OHLC.txt",header = T,sep = ",", 
                colClasses=c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "character"))
```

Здесь мы указали типы данных для первых 4-х колонок, соответственно строковый, числовой, числовой, строковый. Теперь данные в колонке TIME будут восприниматься как строка и первый ноль не будет отбрасываться:

```
  X.TICKER. X.PER.  X.DATE. X.TIME. X.OPEN. X.HIGH.  X.LOW. X.CLOSE. X.VOL. X.OI.
1    EURUSD      5 20180307  080500 1.24210 1.24219 1.24201  1.24214    117     0
2    EURUSD      5 20180307  081000 1.24217 1.24249 1.24212  1.24236    165     0
3    EURUSD      5 20180307  081500 1.24235 1.24279 1.24232  1.24259    251     0
4    EURUSD      5 20180307  082000 1.24260 1.24273 1.24238  1.24248    196     0
5    EURUSD      5 20180307  082500 1.24247 1.24262 1.24241  1.24259    173     0
6    EURUSD      5 20180307  083000 1.24257 1.24310 1.24242  1.24302    281     0
7    EURUSD      5 20180307  083500 1.24298 1.24327 1.24291  1.24310    204     0
```

Далее Вы должны работать с этими данными уже как со строками.